# Pausar ejecución de foreach hasta que termine otro

Tags: php

Tengo un script que comprueba si existen unos datos en mysql y si no existen los inserta o borra según sea necesario.

esta hecho con dos foreach. el primero comprueba si hay datos nuevos en el formulario que no estén en mysql y si los hay los inserta, el segundo comprueba si hay datos en mysql que ya no estén en el formulario y si los hay los borra.

el caso es que al ejecutarse todo de una vez siempre borra y quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de pausar la ejecución del codigo o no ejecutarlo hasta que no termine el primer loop.

el código que uso es este:

```
$UpTallicolor = CartesianProduct(array('tallas'=> $_POST['tallas'], 'color'=> $_POST['colores']));
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUptallicolor) {
    $CExisteArt = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' AND `1`='".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."' AND `2`='".$DUptallicolor['color']."' ");
    if (!$CExisteArt) {   //si no existe ese articulo en los codigos
       $UpTallicolor = Insertar_Datos("Codigos" , "`que`,`idcosa`,`1`,`2`" , "'Codigo','".$_POST["nuevo"]."','".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."','".$DUptallicolor['color']."' "); 
    }
} //cierro el foreach

$QuenoHay = []; 
$Quehay = Consulta_Dinamica("Array","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' ");
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUpColorTalli) {
    $QuenoHay[] = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' AND `1`='".$DUpColorTalli['tallas']."' AND `2`='".$DUpColorTalli['color']."' ");
}

$Diferencia = array_diff_assoc($Quehay,$QuenoHay);
foreach($Diferencia as $BorrarCod) {
    $BorrarCodigos = Borrar_Datos("Codigos" , "id","".$BorrarCod["id"]."");
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `Consulta_Dinamica`?¿qué es lo que devuelve?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es un query a mysql y devuelve un array

Comment: @Killpe no entiendo, donde esta el thread? o la llamada al otro código? de lo contrario esto no tiene sentido...

Comment: @nikomaster que es thread? y que no tiene sentido? las funciones? el como están hechos?

Comment: @Killpe todo tiene su thread(hilo), en tu caso es el principal, por ese (thread) va un iterador, ese iterador trabaja de acuerdo al orden de tu código, ejemplo: si hay una instrucción foreach(); y luego le sigue otra igual, la segunda instrucción no se ejecutará ya que el iterador esta en la primera, por eso mismo digo que esto no tiene sentido...

Comment: @nikomaster vale, pongo la actualización del código que tengo a ver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, podemos "optimizar" un poco este código quitando un foreach extra.

```
$QuenoHay = []; 
$UpTallicolor = CartesianProduct(array('tallas'=> $_POST['tallas'], 'color'=> $_POST['colores']));
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUptallicolor) {    
  $CExisteArt = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' AND `1`='".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."' AND `2`='".$DUptallicolor['color']."' ");
  if (!$CExisteArt) {   //si no existe ese articulo en los codigos
    $UpTallicolor = Insertar_Datos("Codigos" , "`que`,`idcosa`,`1`,`2`" , "'Codigo','".$_POST["nuevo"]."','".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."','".$DUptallicolor['color']."' "); 
  }    
  $QuenoHay[] = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' AND `1`='".$DUpColorTalli['tallas']."' AND `2`='".$DUpColorTalli['color']."' ");
} //cierro el foreach

$Quehay = Consulta_Dinamica("Array","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' ");
```

Segundo, la ejecución de tu código es secuencial, esto quiere decir que si insertas una regla para la ejecución del código esta se cumplirá o no. Aunque leyendo este código, solamente se borran cosas si `$Diferencia` tiene datos; probablemente lo que necesitas es cambiar los resultados de `$Quehay` y `$QuenoHay`

```
$Diferencia = array_diff_assoc($Quehay,$QuenoHay);
if(count($Diferencia) > 5){
  foreach($Diferencia as $BorrarCod) {
   $BorrarCodigos = Borrar_Datos("Codigos" , "id","".$BorrarCod["id"]."");
  }
} else { 
  echo "No ejecuté nada porque no hay más de 5 diferencias...";
}
```

Por último, el segundo `foreach` va a ejecutarse cuando termine el primero **siempre**; esa es la manera en la que funciona PHP.

Comment: A ver, esto viene de dos select multiples, que puede ser que se se agreguen datos, que se borren o ambas dos. Por eso primero inserto y luego borro, el array_diff me saca bien los datos si solo borro, pero si he insertado algo nuevo como todavía no está guardado lo da por qué no está y borra lo que tiene que borrar y lo nuevo ya que en el array_diff da como diferencia todo... total que creo que me he liao explicándolo 

Comment: No pasa nada, todo bien con la explicación... solo hay que mover de lugar el `SELECT` para que suceda después de insertar los registros . Edité mi respuesta para reflejarlo. :)

Comment: el count mayor que 5 es por algo en especial? o lo puedo poner en 1? de momento no va y hace lo mismo que me hacia a mi, pero creo que es porque tengo un cacao con esto que no puedo con mi vida y como se ejecuta con un .load de javascript en segundo plano y no me deja registro ni veo lo que hace ni si falla la sintaxis me trae un poco el camino de la amargura, pero entiendo que poniendo el contador de diferencia ya tengo el pause que necesitaba. Mañana ya mas concentrado lo reviso todo que fijo que así si me va. Mil gracias po tu ayuda :)

Comment: No, el contador en 5 es solo para que exista una regla, puedes dejarlo mayor a 0 para saber que si hay registros se va a ejecutar y de lo contrario no pasa nada... Espero puedas resolverlo pronto :)

Comment: seguro que si  es cuestión de ver qué sale en el array

Comment: Al final solo tenia que cambiar el orden de ejecución de la consulta, primero borro y luego agrego lo nuevo y todo ok. Mil gracias por tu ayuda te doy mis dies